# Individual JS file long Waiting (TTFB) time

Tags: javascript, iis, windows-server-2012

In my VPS windows server, I hosted my website on it. And the website scripts included CDN path and server local path (in /js folder).

However, sometimes I discovered the web page loading is super slow and hence I opened the browser development tool to take a look.

There are several scripts were placed under "/js" folder, and the browser can download normally (takes less than 100 milliseconds in average).

I wonder why the waiting time is so long and how can I fix it? (In server setting?)

Note: I have already set `<script src="/js/controller.js" defer></script>` but still not works... The browser keeps showing blank page until to script finished loading.

[image: The browser takes 1.7 minutes to download controller.js file.]

[image: The browser normally takes milliseconds to download controller.js file.]